# Optimizing Neural Network Keras Regressor

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, regression

I have created a keras regressor model to predict nitrate concentrations from several land cover attributes. However, I am not sure how to interpret the following outcomes:

- loss: 0.0517
- mean_squared_error: 0.0517
- mean_absolute_error: 0.1988
- val_loss: 0.0357
- val_mean_squared_error: 0.0357
- val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1416

Are these values After 1000 epochs sufficient and what do they say about this model(significant or not)? I am new to coding.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

dataset=np.loadtxt("N_LANDCOV.csv", delimiter=",")
x=dataset[:,:-1]
y=dataset[:,-1]
y=np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
print(scaler.fit(x))
print(scaler.fit(y))
xscale=scaler.transform(x)
yscale=scaler.transform(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xscale, yscale)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(28, input_dim=12, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=10,  verbose=1, validation_split=0.33)

Epoch 1000/1000
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 702us/step - loss: 0.0517 - mean_squared_error: 0.0517 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1988 - val_loss: 0.0357 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0357 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1416

import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

print(history.history.keys())
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
plt.figure(figsize=(200, 200))
```

[loss vs epoch graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp7Sh.png)

Comment: The errors are simply the mean square/absolute difference between the real and model-predicted outputs. You have used validation split, so the 'val' errors are the same values calculated on the validation data subset. Considering you have normalized the data between -1 and 1, the average errors do seem proportionally high.

Comment: Am I right in observing that only 30 data samples are used to train the network? (https://machinelearningmastery.com/much-training-data-required-machine-learning/)

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply. The data set has 12 attributes each with 62 samples excluding the one 1 predictive attribute. I have used a split of 0.33, thus around 20 samples are used to train if I am not mistaking.

Comment: What would you suggest to improve this model?

Comment: I would start by getting a lot more data, if that is possible. With 12 inputs (hence 12 input dimensions) there is a very large search space; your data samples are likely incredibly sparse.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to get more data for your model.
As rightly said by @PJRobot , **there is too large search space with less data samples.**

You can also do some pre-processing to **reduce dimensions** for analysis ( if it is possible with the features available). 
But try getting more data before you apply a Neural Network Regressor.
Also try changing the `metric` to `'accuracy'` if you cant understand your current metric findings(they are simply loss values).

I used `accuracy` in my earlier days of Deep Learning to understand my model capabilities.(That was classification)
Also in Regression , try to stick to error metrics as it gives more prominent inferences.

Also try some hyper-parameter tuning for better results.

Happy Learning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and it has shown indeed a very low accuracy Epoch 1000/1000
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 666us/step - loss: 0.0437 - acc: 0.0333 - val_loss: 0.0395 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00. What would you suggest to use as hyper-parameter tuning?

Comment: Neural Networks can leave you speech less with what they can achieve using lots of data . But there has to be alot of data though. If your accuracy is really low , tuning might not totally change your performance. It "enhances and not changes" the performance of your model . However if you are going with tuning , try changing the Batch Size , Epochs and Optimizers as a start. Later you could also add/remove hidden layers if it helps .

Comment: Accuracy is not a valid measure for regression, it is used for classification algorithms. Accuracy is a percentage of solutions where predicted value is exactly the same as the real value. For example if predictions are off by only an infinitesimally small amount (considered good regression performance), then the accuracy will be very low.

Comment: @PJRobot You are correct for sure. The whole point of a metric I believe depends on the purpose of modelling .In Regression , one can intuitively ask ,"I want to find out how much am I deviating from my predictions". Hence MSE and R-Square can be your answer. So I totally agree with you. In my answer I wanted him to focus more on gathering more data and checking for better results.

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful suggestions @PJRobot